# Get specific info between two certain points in a text file using C

Tags: c, text-files

So i have this text file that contains what a person with certain email likes:

```
email1@gmail.com
Likes:
Animals
Sports

email2@gmail.com
Likes:
Science
Animals
```

What i really need are those specific words of what certain user email likes (only one email at the time choosen by scanf) and each liked topic of his (all of them are just one word) is going to be used in a function of my code (ex: function(Animals)).

Edit: I just want each word of what a email that i choose likes (Case email1 i want the word "Animals" and the word "Sports" extracted from the text file because i need to use those words). How can i do that with C?

Comment: And your question is... what is it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you stuck trying to open the file? Are you stuck trying to parse a string? Please show the code where you are stuck and explain exactly what you are having a problem with. As it stands now your question is far to broad for this format.

Comment: I just want each word of what a email that i choose likes (Case email1 i want the word "Animals" and the word "Sports" extracted from the text file because i need to use those words). How can i do that?

Comment: What you want is a data structure that combines email and likes, such as 'struct { char email[max]; list* likes; } user;'. Since likes can have zero/one/many items, you might use a list, vector, dynamic array to store each like. And then you would store all of the users in a list, map, or dynamic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fptr = NULL;
    fptr = fopen("File.txt" , "r");//Let File.txt be the required file
    if(fptr==NULL)//Check if file was opened successfully
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("File opened\n");
    char buff[1024];//To store line read from file
    char email[1024];//To store email id
    printf("Enter email id:");
    scanf("%s",email);
    int found=0;
    while(fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]\n",buff))//Read file line by line and store the line to buff
    {
        //printf(":%s:",buff);

        if(strstr(buff,"@")!=NULL)//Set found=0 if the line in the file is an email id. Here I am checking for the word "@" in the line read since an email id will surely have an @ symbol. Replace it with some checking function to verify if it's an email id
        {
            if(found==1)//If the email was already found break out of the loop
                break;
            found=0;
        }
        if(found==1)//If found=1 buff will have your required Likes including the word Likes:
        {
            if(strcmp("Likes:",buff)!=0)//If required word is not 'Likes:' since only the likes is required not the word 'Likes:'
            {
                printf("%s\n",buff);//buff contains the required like. It can be used as your functions argument.
            }
        }

        if(strcasecmp(email,buff)==0)//Set found=1 if the required email is found 
            found=1;    
        if(feof(fptr))//Break out of the loop if file end is reached
            break;
    }
}
```

If `email1` is the required email id, then your input should be `email1@gmail.com` as it is stored in this format in the file.

Comment: thank you very much, really was struggling with this part